# Adding new item to Firebase node that does not yet exist

Tags: firebase, angularfire

I am using 3-way data binding in an AngularFire app.  For list-based nodes, everything works fine as long as the node already exists.  However, what I'm seeing is that the containing node must be "forced" into existence first with some sort of $update() call.  Just calling $add() does not bring the node into existence.  I have my code working now, but it certainly feels like a hack/workaround to have to update a node with a dummy value before adding a list item.  Can someone confirm this is a bug with AngularFire 3-way data binding, or am I doing something wrong?  Note:  The issue does not happen using the Firebase push() API directly.

Here is a plunker to demonstrate.  The Add button will not work until the "Force New Item" button is clicked.

http://plnkr.co/edit/q81Elp

Answer (score 2):

### The Solution

Use `remoteItems.$add` instead of `$scope.items.$add`.

```
var app = angular.module('plunker', ['firebase']);

  app.controller('MainCtrl', function($scope, $firebase) {

  var fbUrl = 'https://awlcsrqri89.firebaseio-demo.com/';
  var baseRef = new Firebase(fbUrl);
  var newListRef = baseRef.child('parent/newlist');
  var remoteItems = $firebase(newListRef);

  remoteItems.$bind($scope, "items");

  $scope.addItem = function() {
    var newObj = {id: 'abc', name: 'test'};
    remoteItems.$add(newObj);
  };
});
```

### The Explanation

This is not a bug, per se. It stems from the fact that `null` is a very important special value in Firebase. In the vanilla JS SDK, getting a snapshot with a value of `null` means that the data has been loaded, but there simply isn't anything there.

This is important, because in your code an empty `$scope.items` (that is, without the forced value) needs to be `null` to be inline with Firebase's idea that `null` is important. This can cause some issue when we normally add special $ methods onto the data we bind to your scope in AngularFire. So if your data is a number (for example), we can easily add these `$add` methods. However, sometimes the data will be `null` and we can't extend the `null` prototype like we can extend the prototype of a number, string etc.

This leave AngularFire in a pickle. It can't both be inline with Firebase's ideas on `null` and provide the AngularFire methods on the data it binds. The fact it can't put methods on `null` causes your call to `$add` to throw an error. However, once you've put some place holder value and the data becomes not `null`, then AngularFire can give you all the helper methods and everything works.

The solution (as seen above) is simply to use `remoteItems.$add` instead of `$scope.items.$add` because the object `$firebase(...)` returns does not attempt to appear identical to your Firebase data like the data from `$firebase(...).$bind` does. This means, that even when the value should be `null`, the object returned from `$firebase(...)` will not be and will have all methods (including `$add`) available.

Comment: Actually, after further experimentation, I still have a problem.  I agree you always want to call $add() on the remote reference.  Turns out my Plunkr did not accurately capture the issue.  It comes down to calling $bind() on a remote reference that is non-existent.  If you then update your local model, the 3-way binding does not work.  Seems to defeat the intent of the 3-way binding.  You normally want your UI inputs to be bound to your local scope, but that never updates the remote reference if the remote reference was originally null at time of calling $bind().

Comment: Can you provide me a way to reproduce the issue? If you can't host it, just email me the files at abe@firebase.com